# MOSFET Inrush Current limiter

Tags: inrush-current

May I know how to calculate the value of C1, R1, and R2 in the below-shown circuit? The input voltage is 12 V.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the circuit? Do you understand the purpose of each element in the circuit?

Comment: @winny May I Know which tool is suitable to simulate this Circuit?

Comment: The two thing: The R1, R2 divider have to ensure enough voltage between G and S in steady state to mosfet fully open. And set the RC time constant according needs. Do not forget the Fet is in linear region during inrush (causes power stress of fet).

Comment: Beware of mosfet spreads ,What if power is removed and Cin discharges well before C1 discharges then power is suddenly reapplied spiking Cin.

Comment: Falstad, LTspice are two popular ones. Do you understand the function of each component in the schematic?

Comment: @winny can you please elaborate on the function of each component?

Comment: Let's start with what you know and we'll fill in you in from there. What does each component do? What happens when you lower or raise the value of each component.